# Chaining Observables without significant return values

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

I am happily using Retrofit with RxJava in my app, but I don't know how to properly chain network calls which don't really return anything except telling that the call succeeded.

One example is function which sends all updated items to server. First I want to call `loginManager.refreshLogin()` and then `synchronizeInventories()` and `synchronizeItems()`, wait until they are both done and return something indicating the UI can be updated.

Right now, the function looks like this:

```
public Observable<List<Object>> synchronize() {
    return loginManager.refreshLogin()
                    .flatMap(o -> Observable.merge(
                            synchronizeInventories(),
                            synchronizeItems()
                    ))
                    .toList();
}
```

`refreshLogin()` returns `Observable.just(new Object())`, `synchronizeInventories()` and `synchronizeItems()` return `Observable.empty()`.

Everything works now, but I don't think it's the right way to do it.

Comment: What exactly do you think is not right?

Comment: Using things like Observable<Object> to control the flow of execution

Answer (score 1):

`Observable<List<Object>>` is returned because `synchronizeInventories()` and `synchronizeItems()` return different types of objects thus `.merge()` returns an `Observable<Object>`.

If both methods returned same objects then it you be a specific class e.g.:

```
.flatMap(o -> Observable.merge(Observable.just("a"), Observable.just("b")))
.doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(String s) {

    }
 })
```

A way to avoid the general Object class is to use `.zip()` and use the helping `Pair<>` class:

```
.flatMap(o -> Observable.zip(just("a"), just(123), (s, s2) -> new Pair<>(s, s2)))
.doOnNext(pair -> {
    pair.first // get the first object
    pair.second // geth the second
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `concat` to execute a number of Observables in series.

```
    final Observable flowObs = Observable.concat(obs1, obs2, obs3);
    flowObs.subscribe(); //will first execute the subscriber function on obs1, then on obs2, then on obs3
```